# What does "a key is uniform" mean in cryptography?

Tags: random-variables, cryptography

In the lecture on Coursera platform, the inequality below was shown: there exists an algorithm $A$ such that
$$\underset{{k \overset{R}{\longleftarrow} \mathscr{K}}}{\operatorname{Pr}}\left[\left.A(G(k))\right|_{1, \ldots, i}=\left.G(k)\right|_{i+1}\right] \geqslant \frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon$$
Here $\operatorname{G}$ is the pseudorandom generator (PRG) function that expands a seed.

My question: In the lecture, this is stated as "$k$ is uniform in the space of keys $\mathscr K$". I do not understand what uniform means in this context.

A uniform random variable means $P(X=t) = 1/|S|$, where $|S|$ is the set of all possible values (assuming $|S|$ is finite). How to interpretate the meaning of this term "uniform" in the inequality above?

Comment: Is the space $S$ of keys not finite?

Comment: $|S|$ is finite

Comment: Just means uniform random variable .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here  $k$ is indeed uniformly sampled from a finite keyspace $\mathscr{H}$ (a finite set), it's our seed. This space could be something like "all the 256 bit long bytestrings" (so $2^{256}$ possibilities.). So your formula is correct, for a finite set the distribution is simply the uniform distribution over this set, that is what $k \leftarrow \mathscr{H}$ means

In the context of your equation, it means that for a truly uniformly randomly chosen seed $k$, there exists an algorithm $A$ that if given all the previous outputs of the $k$-seeded pseudorandom generator $G$ is able to predict the next one with a probability $1/2 + \epsilon$.

If your PRG is cryptographically secure, then there shouldn't be an algorithm able to do that *in polynomial time*.

If you want to characterize pseudorandom number generators, you may want to look at the notion of computational indistinguishability

Answer (score 0):

The meaning is exactly as you guessed. The key is uniformly distributed in the space $\cal K$ and $k$ shown under $Pr$ in the equation is random sample from this distribution.